# VSCode keeps breaking small objects into multiple lines

Tags: format, visual-studio-code, js-beautify

I don't know what's causing this. I love having auto-format on save. But there is a rule that keeps making objects jump into multiple lines. When I type something like this:

`const { promisify } = require("util");`

VSCode formats it to:

```
const {
    promisify
} = require("util");
```

It looks very ugly.

Answer (score 1):

for html formatting:

"html.format.wrapAttributes": "force-aligned",

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I found it. It was the [beautify plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify).